Alternate methods to solve the following summation without using the beta function
$$
S = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^3 + 9k^2 + 26k + 24} \binom{n}{k}
$$
im aware that the denominator can be factored as (k+2)(k+3)(k+4). but after using partial fractions, im stuck as to how to evaluate it further.

Hint: the denominator can be written as $(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$.

im aware it can be written like that but i dont know how to proceed after it because of the nCk term. splitting it using partial fractions yields three different terms but then i do not know how to evaluate them

Please include more details and what you have tried in the body of your post. If you already know that the denominator has a nice factorisation, it’s better to include it in the post. As written, it’s very likely that this post will be closed.

Hint: Denote
$$Z(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)} \binom{n}{k}\cdot \color{red}{x^{k+4}}$$
then
$$Z'''(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\cdot \color{red}{x^{k+1}} = x(1-x)^n$$
then, it suffices to compute the function $Z(x)$ from its third derivative $Z'''(x)$.

$$
S=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-)^k}{(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}\binom{n}{k}
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-)^k}{2(k+4)}\binom{n}{k}
-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-)^k}{k+3}\binom{n}{k}
+\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-)^k}{2(k+2)}\binom{n}{k}
$$
Then we have in general
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}
(-1)^k\frac{1}{x+k}
=
\frac{N!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+N)}
$$
see  https://doi.org/10.37236/1265 . Cancelling some factorials
$$
S=\frac{3n!}{(4+n)!}-\frac{2n!}{(3+n)!}+\frac{n!}{2(2+n)!}
= \frac{1}{2(3+n)(4+n)}.
$$
